# .NET 4 Entity Framework Issue with Stored Proc Result .ToList()

Tags: .net, entity-framework, stored-procedures, .net-4.0, generic-list

I am using VS2010. .NET 4.0 with the Entity Framwork. I've recently upgraded this code from VS2008 and .NET 3.5 with the older EF. This code works in the old code base.

I've got a stored procedure that I returns a set of valid Locations and I tie with my Merchant data and then take that result set and send it back as a List. When I get there I get the following error:

**This method supports the LINQ to Entities infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.**

I get this error anytime I reference the result variable even in the Watch.

Any ideas?

Here's a bit of code.

```
    public List<Merchant> GetNearest(float miles, float latitude, float longitude)
    {
        var locations = getNearestLocations(miles, latitude, longitude);
        var result = (from ai in locations
                      join b in _entities.Merchant on
                        ai.Merchant.MerchantId equals b.MerchantId
                      select b);

        return result.ToList();
    }

    private IQueryable<Location> getNearestLocations(float miles, float latitude, float longitude)
    {
        var result = (from ai in _entities.AddressInfoWithinRange(miles, latitude, longitude) // this is the call to the Stored Proc
                      join a in _entities.Location on
                        ai.LocationId equals a.LocationId
                      select a).AsQueryable();

        return (IQueryable<Location>)result;
    }
```

Comment: what is `AddressInfoWithinRange`?? is that your stored procedure? if so, you can't join this to other LINQ queries. SP's return `ObjectResult<T>`, which your trying to mesh with `IQueryable<T>`. Not possible without explicit cast. Why are you joining on that SP? Shouldn't the SP doe the join to Location table inside the actual SP?

Comment: You're correct. That's what I figured out last night. AddressInfoWithinRange is the stored proc call.  I'm still trying to figure out how to exactly hold my mouth just right on this one.  Thanks.

Comment: I haven't figured this out yet. The link in the Answer below isn't a fix. I've also tried casting, recasting, and holding my mouth just right to get this to work. I kept getting the same error. I've given up and I'm looping through each and then getting the Merchant for each location. *sigh* Thanks for the advice and help to you both.